# Cerrar el sistema a una hora preestablecida Angular-6

Tags: angular6

Hola necesito que me ayude no tengo ni una idea , desarrolle en angular un sistema para un quiosco y me pidieron que el sistema se cierre de forma automática a las 14 y a las 21   que serian los cambios de turnos .Desde ya gracias .Adjunto el código de cierre que esta armando para un botón.

```
  logout(){
localStorage.removeItem('nombre');
localStorage.removeItem('cargo');
localStorage.removeItem('sucursal');
localStorage.removeItem('idVenta');
this.router.navigate(['/login']);


  this.ventaServi.borrarTemp().subscribe(
    res => {

    }
  );

}
```

Comment: No es recomendable que simplemente cierres la session, podrias quedar a medias de una transaccion. Lo mejor es que lo implementes como regla de negocio, y des un aviso al usuario antes de cerrar abruptamente. Tambien no permitir el login en horario invalido.

Comment: si si lo del aviso lo tenia pensado pero lo de las transaciones no por que el turno termina a las 13 y a las 20 es para que la persona que entra las 15 y a las 08 am no encuentre la session abierta y siga vendiendo con la seccion anterior

Comment: puede ser un reloj que a las 5 horas que se abrió cierre la sección?

Comment: un temporizador quise decir

Comment: Agrega eso a tu pregunta que solo quieres dar un servicio a ciertas horas. Del lado de la interfaz puedes ejecutar un worker o un metodo que verifique la hora y cierre la session despues de cierto horario, y tambien del lado de tu servicio de negocio que cualquier peticion fuera de horario, cierre la sesion y regrese una respuesta personalizada digamos 600 y que tu Interfaz de Usuario se dirija a una pagina Fuera de Servicio cuando reciba ese codigo. El horario de servicio se debe establecer como un parametro en la configuracion.